# Optimization, solving for the 'error' coefficient

Tags: optimization, regression

Given a modified regression equation:

$\hat Y = \exp(\beta_0 + \sum\beta_ix_i + \varepsilon)*F$

where:

$\hat Y = 11353$

$\beta_0 = 8.693021$

$\sum\beta_ix_i = 5.95487177696$

$F = 0.21829$

what is:

$\varepsilon =$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \hat Y = \exp(\beta_0 + \sum\beta_ix_i + \varepsilon)*F \\
\hat Y / F = \exp(\beta_0 + \sum\beta_ix_i + \varepsilon) \\
\ln (\hat Y / F) = \beta_0 + \sum\beta_ix_i + \varepsilon \\
\ln (\hat Y / F) - \beta_0 - \sum\beta_ix_i = \varepsilon $$